minimal sized docker for yesod web server
I am successfully using yesod in my open source security container scanner. Currently, I use multiple services (all running yesod) which is very fast but each docker image is huge compared to other web servers (say python flask, ruby rails, php laravel which are all around 1GB).
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
dhscanner-parsers       latest    b29ba20efc6f   2 days ago    5.66GB # <--- yesod
dhscanner-codegen       latest    2c3c366a36a0   2 days ago    5.64GB # <--- yesod
dhscanner-kbgen         latest    c63e806cc26b   2 days ago    5.63GB # <--- yesod
dhscanner-frontphp      latest    b05d4d3d9cfa   2 days ago    648MB  # <--- php laravel
dhscanner-frontjs       latest    4f49362cf611   2 days ago    1.18GB # <--- js  express

My yesod endpoints receive and return json files, they don't generate *.html files, and don't use any database. Is there any way to make the docker image(s) smaller? The Dockerfile and *.cabal file are from this GitHub repo.
EDIT (requested in comments) - Here is one Dockerfile:
FROM haskell
RUN cabal update
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install vim -y
RUN echo "set number" > ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "set incsearch" >> ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "syntax on" >> ~/.vimrc
WORKDIR /codegen
COPY dhscanner.cabal dhscanner.cabal
RUN cabal build --only-dependencies
COPY dhscanner.ast dhscanner.ast
COPY dhscanner.bitcode dhscanner.bitcode
COPY src src
RUN cabal build
CMD ["cabal", "run"]


Start by finding out what's in it: https://github.com/wagoodman/dive/. Maybe a multi-stage build would be better for final image size, maybe a lighter starting image, ...

Is image size an actual issue? I would think that memory use might be an issue, but image size and memory use don't necessarily correlate.

@HansKilian I'm aiming to use this scanner as a CI/CD workflow - and the cost of launching it depends on how much memory + time it takes - other than that, you're right, using those large images locally is perfectly fine

How critical is it that they be in separate containers? If this is not done for security reasons, then you could consider a single container that forks all five apps, which presumably would be about as big as the largest of the existing containers.

@DanielWagner it's not for security reasons - I guess that moving everything to a single container indeed makes sense

please include at least one Dockerfile in the actual question instead of just linking to it.

@Cubic - I added one Dockerfile ( they are all very similar to that one )

Your Docker image contains everything that's needed to build your
Haskell program and that's likely the reason why your image size blows up.
To fix this you want to use multi-stage builds . Your Dockerfile should include two stages: one for build and one for running the program. The build stage will look very similar to what you currently have but will stop after cabal build.
In the run stage, you should only copy the binary produced by cabal build (using COPY --from ...) and install possible runtime dependencies. Here you should also use a small base image, for example a debian image tagged as slim.
